# Google People API updateContact, batchCreateContacts and batchUpdateContacts throwing Errors

Tags: rest, internal-server-error, google-people-api

The new Google People APIs

1. batchCreateContacts - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchCreateContacts and batchUpdateContacts - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchUpdateContacts gives following response on making a request.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

2. updateContact - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact gives the following response when CalendarUrl is sent in the update contact request

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid updatePersonFields mask path: \"calendar_urls\". Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Can someone help with these issues.

Comment: Can you show a sample request that results in those errors? Mind that a 500 error often is an temporarily error originating from server-side.

Comment: Here is the sample request
`
{
  "readMask": "names",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "contactPerson": {
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
            }
          }
        ],
        "names": [
          {
            "givenName": "Elizabeth"
          }
        ],
        "addresses": [
          {
            "formattedValue": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
            "type": "home"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: Just tried this and it worked perfectly from the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchCreateContacts?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22readMask%22%3A%22names%22%2C%22contacts%22%3A%5B%7B%22contactPerson%22%3A%7B%22memberships%22%3A%5B%7B%22contactGroupMembership%22%3A%7B%22contactGroupResourceName%22%3A%22contactGroups%2FmyContacts%22%7D%7D%5D%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%7B%22givenName%22%3A%22Elizabeth%22%7D%5D%2C%22addresses%22%3A%5B%7B%22formattedValue%22%3A%221600%20Amphitheatre%20Pkwy%20Mountain%20View%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22home%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D).